# call a method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm in an intro programming class, in the lab that I'm currently working on we have to have two classes and pull the methods from one class, "Energy" and have them run in "Energy Driver." 
I'm having trouble calling the methods (testOne, testTwo, testThree) over into "EnergyDriver"

```
   public class EnergyDriver

    {  
   public static void main(String [] args)
     {

  System.out.println(mass1 + " kiolograms, " + velocity1  +
                     "meters per second: Expected 61250," + " Actual " + kineticE1);

  System.out.println(mass2 + " kiolograms, " + velocity2  +
                     "meters per second: Expected 61250," + " Actual " + kineticE2);

   System.out.println(mass3 + " kiolograms, " + velocity3 +
                     "meters per second: Expected 61250," + " Actual " + kineticE3);

    }
    }


  public class Energy

 {  
      public static void main(String [] args)
    {


  public double testOne;
  {
 double mass1;
 double velocity1;
 double holderValue1;
 double kineticE1;

 mass1 = 25;
 velocity1 = 70;

 holderValue1 = Math.pow(velocity1, 2.0);    
 kineticE1   = .5 *holderValue1 * mass1;

 }

  public double testTwo;
  {
 double mass2;
 double velocity2;
 double holderValue2;
 double kineticE2;

 mass2 = 76.7;
 velocity2 = 43;

 holderValue2 = Math.pow(velocity2, 2.0);    
 kineticE2    = .5 *holderValue2 * mass2;


 }

  public double testThree;
  {
 double mass3;
 double velocity3;
 double holderValue3;
 double kineticE3;

 mass3 = 5;
 velocity3 = 21;

 holderValue3 = Math.pow(velocity3, 2.0);    
 kineticE3    = .5 *holderValue3 * mass3;


 }
}
```

Comment: Can you parse the `Energy` class down to just the places where you're trying to call `EnergyDriver` methods (or vice versa, whatever is calling the other).

Comment: Please format your code blocks as if you were turning it into your professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java programs have **SINGLE** point of entry and that is through the *main* method.
Therefore in a single project only one class should have the main method and when compiler will look for that when you run it.
Remember that static methods cannot access non static methods hence main is static therefore it can not access testone two nor three UNLESS you create and object of that type. Meaning in the main method you can have `Energy e = new Energy()` then access those methods that were not declared with keyword static like `e.testone()` .

However take note that non static methods can access static methods through `Classname.Method` name because keyword static entails that only a single copy of that method/variable exists therefore we do not need an object to access it since only one copy exists.

I recommend watching the Java videos from Lynda.com or reading the books Java Head First and Java How To Program (Deitel,Deitel) to give you a boost on your Java knowledge they come with alot of exercises to enhance your knowledge.

Also there are plenty of other questions like this on SO search for them

Answer (score 1):

You must have only one **main** method in any one of class. To call a method from another class you can create an **object** of that class a call their respective method. Another way is by keeping the calling method to be static so you can access that method via **Classname.Methodname**.

```
 public class EnergyDriver
 {  
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     Energy energy=new Energy();
      System.out.println(mass1 + " kiolograms, " + velocity1  +
                 "meters per second: Expected 61250," + " Actual " + energy.testOne());

      System.out.println(mass2 + " kiolograms, " + velocity2  +
                 "meters per second: Expected 61250," + " Actual " + energy.testTwo());

       System.out.println(mass3 + " kiolograms, " + velocity3 +
                 "meters per second: Expected 61250," + " Actual " + energy.testThree());

 }
 }
 class Energy
 {  

 public double testOne()
 {
    double mass1;
    double velocity1;
    double holderValue1;
    double kineticE1;

    mass1 = 25;
    velocity1 = 70;

    holderValue1 = Math.pow(velocity1, 2.0);    
    kineticE1   = .5 *holderValue1 * mass1;

    return kineticE1;
 }

  public double testTwo()
 {
double mass2;
double velocity2;
double holderValue2;
double kineticE2;

mass2 = 76.7;
velocity2 = 43;

holderValue2 = Math.pow(velocity2, 2.0);    
kineticE2    = .5 *holderValue2 * mass2;

return kineticE2;
 }

public double testThree()
{
double mass3;
double velocity3;
double holderValue3;
double kineticE3;

mass3 = 5;
velocity3 = 21;

holderValue3 = Math.pow(velocity3, 2.0);    
kineticE3    = .5 *holderValue3 * mass3;

return kineticE3;
}
}
```

You can get the value of Kinetic Engergy 1,2,3 by using this code.

You can also use the below code which will use only one method to calculate different values by giving different arguments.

```
 public class EngergyDriver 
 {
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
     Energy energy=new Energy();
     double mass=25;
     double velocity=70;         
      System.out.println(mass+ " kiolograms, "+velocity+"meters per second: Expected  61250," + " Actual " + energy.testOne(mass,velocity));  

    }
}
  class Energy
{  

 public double testOne(double mass, double velocity)
 {
    double mass1;
    double velocity1;
    double holderValue1;
    double kineticE1;

    mass1 = 25;
    velocity1 = 70;

    holderValue1 = Math.pow(velocity1, 2.0);    
    kineticE1   = .5 *holderValue1 * mass1;

    return kineticE1;
 }

 }
```